# Shared Packages Issue on marketplace

Tags: magento2, theme, extensions, marketplace, package

I have an issue while submitting a theme on marketplace.
My theme has 3 modules. I have uploaded those modules in shared package because those modules depends on theme package. I have created a simple package for theme in the themes section. I'm not able to mention required modules for theme in composer.json file. Marketplace throws installation error when I mention my shared package names in the composer.json file of the theme

Expected result:
When someone tries to install theme package it should install its dependent shared packages module.

Actual Result:
It just installs the theme package. It is not downloading the shared packages module which I'm already selecting while submitting my theme.

Now my questions:

1. How can a user install a complete package along with its shared packages.?
2. My Main package is the theme package so i cannot mention the list of required modules in composer.json file of theme. So how can I let the user to install shared packages as well?
3. How does marketplace shared packages work. ?
4. How can metapackage help me ?